# Adaptive product filters for WooCommerce

Tags: filters, taxonomy, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

**1.**
I want to create a filter with adaptive product attributes, in woocommerce.

Example: I am in product category A, I select the value red from the color filter attribute. After this, only red products are shown, but also from this point I need to show in the filters only attributes which only red-color products have.

Any ideas on how to do this?

I tried looping all red products and get their attributes, so I can hide all other unnecessary attributes. Evidently, this solution is not efficient at all.

**2.** Also, is there any DB query to return "All attributes of products under category A / subcategory AA ..." ?

*Clarification:*

- An attribute is a taxonomy and an attribute value is a term.
- `color` is taxonomy and `red` is a term

Comment: Do you mean `color` is taxonomy and `red` is a term? Are you using ajax?

Comment: Yes and yes. I also edited the question.

Comment: it would be better if you post some code in your question such as html markup, ajax function etc you have tried or you want.

Answer (score 0):

The way WordPress handles this by default is not ideal - they provide the WP_Query object - through that, you can add whatever filters you like but there's no easy way I know of to create adaptive filters.

That's one of the reasons I created my Faster Woo Widgets plugin - it does exactly what you're looking for - it lets you create category widgets with either adapative or standard filters - if you choose adaptive, then a category list of 10 items will become, for example, a list of only 2 items once you have selected the colour Red.

https://www.wpintense.com/knowledgebase/adaptive-filters/

The way I handle this code is through my own custom SQL code. It's a join from wp_posts to wp_taxonomies and the related tables from there.